# PodamFactory is not setting fields with annotations

Tags: java, unit-testing, jemos-podam

I am doing unit tests for my classes and I use PodamFactoryImpl to fill objects with dummy data.

PROBLEM:
It seems that the fields that have annotations like @NotEmpty (from javax.validation.constraints) are NULL.

Is there any way I can configure the PodamFactoryImpl instance to fill all the fields? (like configuring it to ignore annotations)

My filling method:

```
public static <T> T fillObject(Class<T> clazz) {
    PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
    return factory.manufacturePojoWithFullData(clazz);
}
```

My sad example POJO:

```
public class Location {
    @NotEmpty
    private String tenant; //will be null
    @NotEmpty
    private String serviceName; //will be null
    @NotNull
    private List<LocationData> locations; //will be with value
    @NotNull
    private Boolean async; //will be with value
    @NotNull
    private Long companyIndex; //will be with value
    @NotEmpty
    private String topicId; //will also be null
}
```

Comment: I have not used it myself, but it looks like you need a DataProviderStrategy https://mtedone.github.io/podam/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of BeanValidationStratagy. This class is used in case of annotations and generates incorrect data.
You can customize generation the way you need by adding attribute strategy per your annotation class.

```
PodamFactoryImpl podamFactory = new PodamFactoryImpl(); 
((RandomDataProviderStrategy) podamFactory.getStrategy()).addOrReplaceAttributeStrategy(MyUrlConstraintAnnotation.class, (attrType, attrAnnotations) -> "https://www.company.com/");
```

Answer (score -1):

You will be upgrade artifact version

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
    <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```